# Redirect para url com tabs bootstrap 4

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho esse código html utilizando as tabs do bootstrap:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-fotos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-fotos-tab">
        <br>
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="form-group btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cadastraFoto">
                <span class="fas fa-plus"></span>&nbsp; Incluir
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="read_content" id="read_content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

E um redirect no PHP,

```
 $redirect = "retorno.php?id=" . $id . "#nav-fotos&deleted";
 header("location:$redirect");
```

Preciso que esse redirect vá para exatamente a tab #nav-fotos, porém não está funcionando, esse código.

Quando clico ele redireciona para a pagina `retorno.php` mais não vai para tab nav-fotos

Comment: Colocando assim: `retorno.php##nav-fotos` não funciona?